# How do I dynamically add an array to a react-bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a React component that will render a table based on data from an Ajax call. There might just be one row of data, or there might be a maximum of N rows(not a huge amount, but there's a limit).

Using `react-bootstrap`, how would I create a table depending on the data I get from `this.state.data`?

Here's some sample code from `render` of the class. How would I populate the individual cells depending on the length of my array?

The array contains an object for each row I wish to populate, with data corrosponding to `Name` and `Address` as well as `Age`(just an example). How do I populate the `<td>`'s with the right amount? It might be anywhere from 1 to N.

```
render : function () {


        let personArray = []; // Array containing objects that each match the three columns I wish to populate. 


        for(let i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++){
            console.log(personArray[i]); // Prints correctly each object with three value key pairs inside
        }

        const popoverLeft = (

            <Popover id="popover-positioned-left" title="Country name">
                <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        // Goes on .. 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        // Goes on .. 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        // Goes on .. 
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </Popover>
        );

        return(
            <div>
                <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="right" overlay={popoverLeft}>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like this :

In your render :

```
<Table striped condensed hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {personArray.map(this.renderPerson)}
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

Your renderPerson function :

```
renderPerson(person, index) {
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{person.name}</td>
      <td>{person.address}</td>
      <td>{person.age}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}
```

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) function will iterate over your array and return a new array of elements to render.

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Shouldn't `renderPerson` be `function renderPerson` in your example, though?

Comment: I wrote this using ES6 syntax so you're right, you'll have to tweak it for your syntax needs :)